# Should I be concerned about return "(str) ['item1', 'item2' ]"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyvmomi

I'm trying to return a list in one of my methods for interacting with vmware via pyvmomi.

```
active_list = self.vss.spec.policy.nicTeaming.nicOrder.activeNic
```

when I do `return active_list` I get:

```
(str) [
   'vmnic0',
   'vmnic1'
]
```

Type:

```
type(active_list)
<class 'pyVmomi.VmomiSupport.str[]'>
```

Since I'm able to iterate over the `active_list` as it is, shoud I be concerned about the `(str)` prefix.

I was able to avoid the `(str) [...]` prefix by 
coping `active_list`, `new_list=list(active_list)`

What is the best pythonic approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `(str)` prefix comes from the [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) representation of the `<class 'pyVmomi.VmomiSupport.str[]'>`. Obviously the class also supports iterating, so you can loop over it.

You can learn more about special method names in the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).

As long as you don't rely on the `str()` output of that class / instance you can ignore it.

Comment: what do you mean by `don't rely on the str()` it returns the items as strings

Comment: Not exactly, it gives you the items as string in a list as string, but it is not really a list. Is is in fact only a representation of this class. You can't use this representation as a list as-it.

Comment: So I guess I'm safer with useing `new_active_list = list(active_list)` since I want to do comparison of lists `if set(active_list) == set(some_other_list)`

Comment: You could also compare your lists with the raw `active_list` instance, but this is also a good approach